# Looking at attaching metal legs to a table top

Tags: tabletop, strength, stability

Basically I have some standard metal tubing square legs which I want to affix to a table base. Hopefully the pics attached below show my idea but I am thinking of attaching a wood block on the underside of the metal leg using two metal bolts. Put two pieces of wood on either side of the leg forming part of the apron around it and then attach the metal legs to the apron using custom dowels similar to how it's done in this video https://youtu.be/F-SxsnG7CLc just without glueing it to the top. Alternatively I could just glue together rather than using the dowels.

Once the table is attached to the apron using cleats the metal legs will be wedged between the table top and the apron to which it is joined.

The table is a mix of Australian brushbox and spotted gum weighing around 100kg. Dimensions 2.4m X 1.2m X 320mm. The apron will be straight brushbox dimensions 2m X 800mm X 300mm. The metal legs are 730 mm X 700mm

Looking for advice regarding strength, stability and whether there is a better way to do this.

[image]]
[image]]
[image]]

Comment: Welcome to WSE.  I assume that you are looking for input regarding the stability/strength of your design. It would be helpful if you include a question to be answered. Also, if you include information regarding wood types &sizes along with overall dimensions and how you intend to attach the legs to the apron and the top to the apron/leg assembly you may get much better input.

Comment: Well this is **a** way you could do this, it's not the way I'd approach it but I don't see any reason this wouldn't work if you get your fit right (i.e. good and snug). Did you specifically want to embed the legs in this manner or is it just the only way you could think of attaching them?

Comment: Hi Graphus, I am not locked into the idea of embedding the legs just did not want to screw them into the table top like you see everyone else do. Have had a look around but can seem to find any designs where they are allowing for wood movement and support the length of the table. How would you approach it?

Comment: The place where you'll have to worry about wood movement with this design is the attachment between this apron and your table top.  If the top is made of wood you'll have to allow for movement across its width.

Comment: *"support the length of the table"* I am reading the dimension of the top correctly, it is 320mm thick right? You don't need to support its length! This will be *massively* stiff. Given this, you can ditch the entirety of the apron and simply attach the leg frames to the tabletop in any way that allows for movement. The simplest solution I can see is to epoxy a few of my favourite tabletop fasteners to the metal and once the epoxy has fully cured just screw the tabletop on through the appropriate slots (the ones at right angles to the grain). Bish bash bosh, done, and no woodworking needed :-)

Comment: Are you thinking something like this with slots for wood movement http://www.leevalley.com/us/wood/page.aspx?p=67857&cat=3,43648,43649&ap=1

Comment: Practical considerations.  The wood box will interfere with the feet of people seated at the table..  The inside of the box will be a nuisance to clean.  A friend has a redwood table -- 5 x 12 foot table taht is a 3" slab of redwood.  The supports are two 18" at the top x 24 inch at the bottom redwood tree stumps. I don't remember the details of the attachment.  It may have been gravity.